# Cord showing near bead

Tags: tire

What could be causing this? Tires are about 200 miles old. Used almost exclusively on smooth, cleaned asphalt. Sometimes gravel.

Also - is the tire still safe?

[image]

Comment: Is it only this section, or around all/most of the rim? Is it possible the wheel was incorrectly installed and rubbing brakes at some stage, but now its sitting correctly and looks good?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that your brakes are misaligned & are rubbing on the tire.
The brake pad should be centered on the rim braking surface, look closely & you will likely see that the pad contacts the tire when the lever is pulled.

Not only does the pad touching the tire wear out the sidewall, but it also generates heat which damages the tire & inner tube which could cause a catastrophic blowout.

I would fix the brakes & then immediately replace the the tire(s).

Comment: that's what I thought too - but I've looked at the brake pads. There is no way they are hitting the tire at that point unless they were positively jumping up and down while I grab at the brakes.

Comment: I did adjust the pads further downward because admittedly they would touch the upper part of the braking track before but if you look at the picture the upper part of the braking track is still a good distance away from where the wear is.

Comment: So they touched at the upper part of the braking track.  On an inflated tire that wear point is the likely first point of contact.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the brakes so we can see the mounting & contacting areas?

Comment: **Something** is rubbing against the tire.  I had this happen with my front tire last summer when I replaced the wheel and readjusted the brakes (due to the change in rim width) and didn't get it right -- it looked OK on casual examination, but when the brakes were full on they were rubbing.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure there's no movement in the brake or pads under real life braking conditions.  If something is loose, the brake will pivot around where it's mounted on the fork crown causing the pads to move upward under harsh braking conditions. Such a problem might not be apparent when if you are just looking at the problem on the repair stand. Put some chalk around the wall of the tire to see where it is rubbing off.

Comment: Brakes are the touch point but may not be the cause. Wheel problems - miss alignment or sideways movement, frame problems (cracks) - flex under cornering. In all cases the less obvious, the more serious the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

There is something rubbing the tire. Brake pads are the likely suspect. Does the tire look like this all the way around? On both sides? On front & rear?

Answer (score 0):

It could also be from one of those bike stands which hold the bicycle just by its front wheel (which is also bad for the wheel of course).

Though I also think it’s more likely that the brake pads or maybe even the frame (if it’s a tight road bike frame) are rubbing. Is it the back wheel? Maybe it only happens under heavy load because the frame or wheel gets twisted.

[image: Bicycle stand]